# Counting object variable ocurrence with switch statement not working

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement, counting

I'm just learning Java and I'm trying to make program that counts the number of times that a district or "cuadrante" as it's called in the program has a ticket or "multa" the problem is, that the way I'm doing it returns strange results. For example if I input cuadrante 1 for each loop, I get a count of

cuadrante1: 3
cuadrante2: 3
cuadrante3: 3
cuadrante4: 3

when it should be:
cuadrante1: 3
cuadrante2: 0
cuadrante3: 0
cuadrante4: 0

So, I was wondering what's wrong with this.

Hope you can help me.
Thanks

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package multas;

/**
 *
 * @author sanikte
 */
public class Multas {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int cuadrante1 = 0, cuadrante2 = 0, cuadrante3 = 0, cuadrante4 = 0;

        NewMulta[] multa = new NewMulta[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < multa.length; i++) {
            multa[i] = new NewMulta();
            multa[i].changeCuadrante();
            multa[i].changeRegistroVehiculo();
            multa[i].changeVelocidadLimite();
            multa[i].changeVelocidadRegistrada();
            multa[i].imprimirReporte();
            multa[i].calcularInfraccion();

            switch (multa[i].cuadrante) {
                case 1:
                    cuadrante1++;
                case 2:
                    cuadrante2++;
                case 3:
                    cuadrante3++;
                case 4:
                    cuadrante4++;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Cuadrantes" + cuadrante1 + cuadrante2 + cuadrante3 + cuadrante4);

    }
}


    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package multas;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author sanikte
 */
public class NewMulta {
    int cuadrante = 0;
    int velocidadLimite = 0;
    int velocidadRegistrada = 0;
    int infraccion = 0;

    String registroVehiculo = "No especificado";

     int changeCuadrante(){
        int newCuadrante;
        System.out.println("Ingrese el cuadrante en el que se ha presentado la multa:  1, 2, 3 o 4 y presione enter: \r");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        newCuadrante = teclado.nextInt();
        cuadrante = newCuadrante;
        return cuadrante;  
    }

    String changeRegistroVehiculo(){
        String newRegistroVehiculo;
        System.out.println("Ingrese el VIN \r");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        newRegistroVehiculo = teclado.next();
        registroVehiculo = newRegistroVehiculo;
        return registroVehiculo; 
    }

    int changeVelocidadLimite(){
        int newVelLimite;
        System.out.println("Ingrese velocidad límite del área: ");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        newVelLimite = teclado.nextInt();
        velocidadLimite = newVelLimite;
        return velocidadLimite;
    }

    int changeVelocidadRegistrada(){
        int newVelocidadRegistrada;
        System.out.println("Ingrese velocidad en la que iba el conductor: ");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        newVelocidadRegistrada = teclado.nextInt();
        velocidadRegistrada = newVelocidadRegistrada;
        return velocidadRegistrada;
    }

    int calcularInfraccion(){

        int diferencia;
        diferencia = velocidadRegistrada - velocidadLimite;
        infraccion = diferencia * 1250;
        System.out.println(infraccion);
        return infraccion;
    }





    void imprimirReporte(){
    System.out.println ("La información es: \r Cuadrante: "+ cuadrante +"\r Velocidad límite: " 
            + velocidadLimite + "\r Velocidad registrada: "+ velocidadRegistrada + "\r VIN: "+registroVehiculo+"\r Cantidad a pagar: "+ infraccion );
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Fall Through.**

You have to add the `break` after each case. Otherwise, it increments all the variables.

```
switch (multa[i].cuadrante) {
            case 1:
                cuadrante1++;
                 break;
            --
            default:
                break;
        }
```